# Calling post method from another controller's view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

**Problem:** Hi there, so in a view where a product is displayed I have a button to call post method to add this product in the cart but the button does not do it at all.

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add to cart" asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"/>
</div>
```

And this is the method in the cart's controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int productId)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("HelloCartAdd!");
    //Some logic.
    return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Product", productId);
}
```

Comment: you are using tag helper, have you added the tag helper reference on your view?

Comment: That was the right answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the route parameter is defined as `asp-route-id="@Model.Id"` the action method should use 'id' parameter name:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int id)
{          
    ...
}
```

If the `[HttpPost]` attribute is applied to the action method add the `formmethod="post"` attribute to the `<input>` tag. I suppose the button is already located inside the form.

```
<form>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" formmethod="post"  value="Add to cart" asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" />
</form>
```

Comment: You are right about the route param too. I did a mistake theye naming it productId but also adding a method="post" fixed it. Thanks!